# How to change the color of this custom progress bar using Java instead of using XML?

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner to Android and Java. I have some trouble setting this custom loading animation I found on GitHub. https://ybq.github.io/Android-SpinKit/.

I've implemented it directly in to my code using Java as below and it works.

```
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
Sprite threeBounce = new ThreeBounce();
progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(threeBounce);
```

But I want to change the color of it from code without using XML. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately this Library offers a method called `setColor`.

You can use this code, the progressBar will be blue then:

```
SpinKitView progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
Sprite threeBounce = new ThreeBounce();
threeBounce.setColor(Color.BLUE);
progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(threeBounce);
```